# On algebraicity of a formal power series

Tags: power-series, noncommutative-algebra, formal-power-series

In his paper "Noncommutative identities" M. Kontsevich states the following:

> **Theorem 2.** *For any $P=P(x,y)=1+\cdots\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ expand
>   $$\log(P)=\sum_{n,m}f_{n,m}x^ny^m\in\mathbb{C}[[x,y]].$$
>   Then the series
>   $$\exp\left(\sum_{n,m}{n+m \choose n}f_{n,m}x^ny^m\right)$$
>   is algebraic*.

The hint he gives is to *use the residue formula twice*. I've wasted hours and hours trying to make sense of this statement, but none of my efforts have led anywhere, the main one being:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n,m}{n+m \choose n}f_{n,m}x^ny^m & =\sum_{n,m}\text{"Tr"}\bigg((X+1)^n(X^{-1}+1)^m\bigg)f_{n,m}x^ny^m \\
& = \text{"Tr"}\left(\sum_{n,m} f_{n,m}\bigg((X+1)\cdot x\bigg)^n\bigg((X^{-1}+1)\cdot y\bigg)^m\right) \\
& =-\text{"Tr"}\left( \sum_{k\ge1}\frac{Q^k\bigg((X+1)\cdot x,(X^{-1}+1)\cdot y\bigg)}{k} \right) \\
& =- \sum_{k\ge1}\frac{\text{"Tr"}\left( Q^k\bigg((X+1)\cdot x,(X^{-1}+1)\cdot y\bigg) \right)\tau^k}{k}\bigg|_{\tau=1}
\end{align*}

Where $"\text{Tr}"$ stands for the constant coefficient and X is a (noncommutative) formal variable. Then applying the following construction:
\begin{align*}
\exp\left(-\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{\text{"Tr"}(a^k)}kt^k\right) & = \exp\left(-\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{\text{res}[a^k/z,0]}k t^k\right) = \exp\left(-\frac1{2\pi i}\sum_{k\ge1}\oint_{|z|=\epsilon}\frac{a^k(z)}k t^k\frac{dz}{z}\right)\\
& = \exp\left(\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=\epsilon}\left(-\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{a^k(z)t^k}k d\right)\frac{dz}{z}\right) \\
& = \exp\left(\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=\epsilon}\frac{\log(1-a(z)t)}zdz\right) \\
& = \exp\left(\int \left( \frac1{2\pi i} \oint_{|z|=\epsilon}\frac{-a(z)}{1-a(z)t}\frac{dz}{z}\right)dt\right)\\
\end{align*}

But then looking for the poles of this function in the neighbourhood of the origin doesn't quite work... (for "classical" Laurent polynomials in one variable (i.e with coefficients only in $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$) this worked quite well)

Therefore here I am, looking for any piece of advice to get closer to a palpable result. Many thanks in advance!

PS: The whole paper can be found here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.2469v1.pdf